# Double Pivot across columns is failing

Tags: oracle, pivot

I wrote a code which has got two pivots in the query but it is failing to give any output.The error is : ORA-00904: "THESEUS_ACTIVE": invalid identifier.
Could anyone help me on this

```
SELECT company_id
, MAX(alt_rec_date) alt_rec_date
, rec_date
, MAX(STANDARD) STANDARD
, MAX(THESEUS) THESEUS
, CAST(NVL(MAX(STANDARD_Active), 0) AS NUMBER(1)) STANDARD_Active
, CAST(NVL(MAX(THESEUS_Active), 0) AS NUMBER(1)) THESEUS_Active  --the 
error is here in max(theseus_active)--
FROM (
**SELECT RH.company_id
      ,MAX(RH.alt_rec_date) alt_rec_date
      ,IT.type_code
      ,RH.alt_rec_code rec_code
      ,RH.rec_date
      , CAST(ITC.active AS NUMBER(10)) active
      ,IT.type_code || '_Active' active_type_code
FROM tblInvestTypeRecHist RH
    JOIN tblInvestType IT ON RH.type_code = IT.type_code
    JOIN (
        SELECT company_id, MAX(rec_date) rec_date
        FROM tblInvestTypeRecHist GROUP BY company_id
        ) LR
    ON RH.company_id = LR.company_id AND RH.rec_date = LR.rec_date
    JOIN tblInvestTypeComp ITC 
    ON RH.company_id = ITC.company_id AND IT.type_code = ITC.type_code
GROUP BY RH.company_id
      ,IT.type_code
      ,RH.alt_rec_code 
      ,RH.rec_date
      ,ITC.active**

) Data

PIVOT (
MAX(rec_code)
FOR type_code IN
('STANDARD','THESEUS')
)  pvt

PIVOT (
MAX(active)
FOR active_type_code IN
('STANDARD_Active','THESEUS_Active')
)  pvt

GROUP BY company_id, rec_date;
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't specifying aliases for the pivoted columns, so by default they end up as quoted identifiers set to the values being matched; so you can change the start of your query to:

```
SELECT company_id
, MAX(alt_rec_date) alt_rec_date
, rec_date
, MAX("'STANDARD'") STANDARD
, MAX("'THESEUS'") THESEUS
, CAST(NVL(MAX("'STANDARD_Active'"), 0) AS NUMBER(1)) STANDARD_Active
, CAST(NVL(MAX("'THESEUS_Active'"), 0) AS NUMBER(1)) THESEUS_Active
FROM (
...
```

Notice both the double- and single-quotes, and the case exactly matching the generated string you produced earlier; and that you have to apply quotes to the columns from the first pivot as well as the second pivot.

Alternatively, and probably more readably, give the pivoted columns aliases:

```
SELECT company_id
, MAX(alt_rec_date) alt_rec_date
, rec_date
, MAX(STANDARD) STANDARD
, MAX(THESEUS) THESEUS
, CAST(NVL(MAX(STANDARD_ACTIVE), 0) AS NUMBER(1)) STANDARD_Active
, CAST(NVL(MAX(THESEUS_ACTIVE), 0) AS NUMBER(1)) THESEUS_Active
FROM (
...
) Data

PIVOT (
MAX(rec_code)
FOR type_code IN
('STANDARD' as standard,'THESEUS' as theseus)
)  pvt

PIVOT (
MAX(active)
FOR active_type_code IN
('STANDARD_Active' as standard_active,'THESEUS_Active' as theseus_active)
)  pvt

GROUP BY company_id, rec_date;
```

---

I'm not sure you actually need two pivots here; without sample data and expected results I may well be missing something, but it looks like you might be able to do:

```
...
) Data
PIVOT (
  MAX(rec_code), MAX(active) as active
  FOR type_code IN ('STANDARD' as standard,'THESEUS' as theseus)
)
GROUP BY company_id, rec_date;
```

The whole thing looks like it could probably be simplified though.